# How to test file fields when the file selection is done through a button click?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-io, capybara

In my software, I have a dynamically generated file input that is actually triggered by a button click event, like this: `$('#my-file-input').focus().click()`.

While I could use capybara `attach_file` directly on the file input, I would rather use the button.

I'm already using a web driver to the test. So after click in the button, I can even see the file browser opening, however I can't find a way to automatically select a file. Is there a way I can achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that the file select window cannot be seen by webdriver, as it is outside the DOM.

The same goes for the other browser controls outside the DOM.

On a side note, I remember facing some permission issues (on IE specifically) when the file select is triggered by JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of this permission issues. I'm testing against all supported browsers and my current hack seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to use a different driver, like Webkit, to execute the Javascript when clicking the button:

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#capybara-webkit

> The capybara-webkit driver is for true headless testing. It uses QtWebKit to start a rendering engine process. It can execute JavaScript as well. It is significantly faster than drivers like Selenium since it does not load an entire browser.

After the file upload field is created in the DOM, then you use `attach_file` to select the file.

http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#attach_file-instance_method

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Actually I'm already doing that. On my the click event I have something like `$('#my-file-input').focus().click()`. So when the button is clicked, the file browsing screen is show. I would like to keep testing from there instead of using `attach_file`, to be more consistent with the real usage of the system. I'll improve my question.

Comment: You would have to use a different tool that can capture mouse clicks and native OS window events like http://iewatch.com/wrprofessional.aspx. Look for something that can test Java applets or Flash applications.